# Maven generate-sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to Maven integration on eclipse. I usually use the command "mvn process-sources" to generate-sources using the command line for something like this:

```
`<execution>
    <id>copy-was-dependencies</id>
    <phase>process-sources</phase>
    <goals>
       <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
    </goals>
    <configuration>
       <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
       <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/was</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>`
```

When I right-click the pom.xml, there is no process-sources in the "Run As" option. How can I configure one to use process-sources instead of generate-sources?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `Run Configuration` for Maven, with `process-sources` as goal.
Right-click on your project, `Run As`, `Run Configurations...`

[image: Run Configurations...]

[image: Maven process-sources]

Answer (score 0):

If your generated sources are done exclusively via java annotation procsssors then you can use m2e-apt eclipse plugin which operates on-the-fly and you do not need to do anything. Otherwise you're stuck with a Maven launch configuration as other answers have pointed out.